# Chrome timeline blank painting boxes : what is it?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to improve my page paint time on android, by using remote debug and continuous page repaiting mode.

My page paint is enormous (> 400ms) and I don't understand why. Im my timeline, I have these strange empty painting boxes and I can't find on google what it means.

Please see for yourself :

http://www.serenity-ff.com/images/screenshots/screenshot180105001.jpg

hxxp://www.serenity-ff.com/images/screenshots/screenshot180206001.jpg (sorry cant post two links)

The page is visible here : http://celsiusheroes.com/game/webviews/test.html
Please note that it is a test page, links don't work.

I've noted that removing background images reduces the page paint time by a lot (like 60fps per backgrounds), even if the background isn't visible. It seems strange to me.

Does someone have a clue on what's happening on my page please ? Thanks a lot !

Best regards.